# Sort values in a nested dictionary from min. to max

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I created a dictionary, named `dict_dif` and loaded nested data into the same. The nested structure of this dictionary has the following structure:

1. Variables (four different variables)
2. Regions (eleven different regions for each of the four variables)
3. Data points (60 data points per region).

The dictionary looks as follows (where I shorten the variables, regions and data points to provide a small and better overview):

```
'variable_one': {'V1': [0.2883961843782473,
   -0.2564336831277686,
   -0.1502803806437477,
   -0.3404171090176428,
  'V2': [0.3053319292730037,
   -0.12252840653652636,
   -0.18759593722968465,
   -0.04368054841152297,
'variable_two': {'V1': [0.05129822246425414,
 ...
```

**Aim:** I would like to sort the numeric values from the lowest to the highest for each variable and region, respectively. For example, in the sorted dictionary the numeric values should span from the lowest to the highest for region V1, for region V2, and so on individually for each variable.

I tried the following code (among others) that I found on the internet:

```
sorted_dict = {var : dict(sorted(roi.items(), key = lambda ele: ele[1]))
       for var, roi in dict_dif.items()}
```

However, that code seems to sort the regions based on each region’s first value. Is there a way to adjust this code above (or a different code) so that the order of the variables and regions remains the same, while only sorting the regions’ values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to sort the numeric values for each variable

```
sorted_dict = {
    variable: {region: sorted(values) for region, values in regions.items()}
    for variable, regions in dict_dif.items()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I meant and your code does the job.