# Sorting a deeply nested dictionary from lowest to highest values

Tags: python, dictionary, sorting

I created an empty dictionary labeled `dict_dif = {}` into which I loaded data via a for loop. The resulting dictionary has the following nested structure:

```
dict_dif[var][roi][subject][numeric_value]
```

This means that for each var, roi, and subject, there is a specific numeric value attached. For example, the code `print(dict_dif["acw"]["V1"]["10600"])` would print `0.44242`.

In a previous question ([Sort values in a nested dictionary from min. to max](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77302486/sort-values-in-a-nested-dictionary-from-min-to-max)) I asked how it is possible to sort data from min. to max. values in a dictionary where the key `subject` was missing, and instead each key `roi` contained *a list of values* (instead of a single value assigned to each `[subject]`.

**Problem:** My problem is that I have to remember how each `subject` is connected to each `numeric_value` *after* sorting the dictionary, and this is impossible with my previous attempt. In other words, after sorting the values in my previous attempt (see link above), I no longer know which of the sorted value corresponds to which subject.

**Idea:** To solve this problem, my idea is as follows.
First, I create a distinct key in the dictionary `dict_dif` for each subject as shown above. Each subject key then gets the corresponding numeric value.
Second, I sort this dictionary again from min. to max. numeric values, while the subject information remains.

**Question:** Is it principally possible to sort this nested dictionary from the lowest to the highest numeric values, since each of the nested key structures only has *one value* (so that Python probably cannot understand how to sort the dictionary, because all my attemps so far failed)?

Besides, I wonder if there is a better approach (than my attempt described above) to solve this problem.

Here is what my current dictionary looks like:

```
{'acw': {'V1': {'100610': -0.14749908116389868,
   '102311': -0.0024704496902879514,
   '104416': 0.08791335022154448,
   '105923': -0.14556719812398553,
...
}}}
```

I would like to order the dictionary from lowest to highest values as follows:

```
{'acw': {'V1': {'100610': -0.14749908116389868,
'105923': -0.14556719812398553,
'102311': -0.0024704496902879514,
'104416': 0.08791335022154448,
...
}}}
```

I shortened the dictionary indicated by the three dots `...` because the fully dictionary contains way too much keys.

Comment: At a minimum, please add 1) Example input; 2) Desired output based on that input; 3) What you have tried. The solution here is recursive walk of your nested dict. Google that...

Comment: As the previous commentor stated, you really should provide example input and expected output, and it's required you give us some code you tried. But in general this can be solved with reverse lookups: for each key-value pair in your input dictionary dx, add the value as a key to a new dictionary dy, set to the original key value: dx[a] = b => dy[b] = a. Then you can sort dy however you want, and reverse the process to get your output.

Comment: Thanks, I added both a current state (example) of the dictionary and one state I aim to achieve.

Comment: Can't there be multiple keys at each level of the nesting? Do you just need to sort the deepest levels, or the other levels?

Comment: I only need to sort the deepest level of the numeric values (such as -0.14749908116389868), so that the subjects (such as 100610) are sorted following the lowest to the highest numeric values in the last key.

Comment: So you're basically just asking how to sort a dictionary. The fact that it's nested doesn't change the solution, you'll just assign the sorted result back to the place where you found it.